# Finding an overloaded method using Scala Reflections

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I am trying to find the overloaded method using Scala reflections. Here's my code

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Example {

  class Something {
    def printIt(s1: String,s2: String) {println(s1 + s2) }
    def printIt(s: Int) { println(s) }
    def printIt(s: String) {println(s) }
    def printInt(i: Int) { println(i) }
    def printInt(i: String) { println(i) }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val r = new Something()

    val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val instanceMirror = mirror.reflect(r)
    val symbols = mirror.typeOf[r.type].decl(TermName("printInt")).asMethod

  }
}
```

When I execute the code I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException: value printInt encapsulates multiple overloaded alternatives and cannot be treated as a method. Consider invoking `<offending symbol>.asTerm.alternatives` and manually picking the required method
```

By following the suggestion given by the exception itself, I am able to find the overloaded method by iterating through method alternatives. But is there any way of finding the method using the argument types that the method takes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either using Scala reflection and iterating

```
val m: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = 
  typeOf[Something].decl(TermName("printInt")).asTerm.alternatives.find(s => 
    s.asMethod.paramLists.map(_.map(_.typeSignature)) == List(List(typeOf[Int]))
  ).get.asMethod
```

or using Java reflection

```
val m: java.lang.reflect.Method = 
  Class.forName("Example$Something").getMethod("printInt", classOf[Int])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @Dmytro Mitin